# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported Angular when i serve the project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

When I run the following command, it gives me an error.

```
ng s
```

The error:

> ```
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupportedat new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:145:18)at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)at OriginalSource.updateHash (/Users/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/OriginalSource.js:104:8)at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:868:17)at handleParseResult (/Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:934:10)at /Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1026:4at processResult (/Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:743:11)at /Users/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5 {opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],library: 'digital envelope routines',reason: 'unsupported',code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'}
> ```

`Angular version=v20.9.0`
`node version =v20.9.0`
`Npm version= 10.1.0`

The following command solved it after I ran it in a terminal:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

But every time I open the project, I have to use this command before serving:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
ng s
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you can add it to your shell profile, so it's automatically set every time you open a terminal. (example for bash bellow)

```bash
echo 'export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

2. or try to upgrade your webpack version. the error is from webpack
3. or try to downgrade your node.js